# RestSharp How to use AddDefaultUrlSegment?

Tags: restsharp

Everytime I try to use AddDefaultUrlSegment it does not work.

```
 var client = new RestClient("http://example.com/{test});
       client.AddDefaultUrlSegment("test",123);
```

when I look into fiddler it does this `%7Btest%7D` it is not putting `123` in. If I do the same thing in the Request part it works.

Anyone know what I doing wrong?